# Python Threading Event clear and set timer to block loop doesn't work on Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am trying to set a fixed amount of time for iterations. (let's say each iteration should take exactly 2 seconds). I used:

```
forced_delay = threading.Event()
delay_time = 5
for index,row in dataframe.iterrows():
forced_delay.clear()
        timer = threading.Timer(delay_time , forced_delay.set)
        timer.start()

        if index < 32:
            prev_data.put(row) # put data into queue.Queue()
            continue
        else:
            ... # get data from queue, manipulate and send over using mqtt

        print(f'current index {index}, current flag is {forced_delay._flag}')
        forced_delay.wait()
        print(f'current index {index}, current flag is {forced_delay._flag}')
```

The problem is that event.clear() can not block Queue. So iterations continue despite the timer hasn't set the event. That's why I can not accomplish data transmission at const interval(in example it's 5sec)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is way overcomplicated. Why not just use time.sleep(5)? And if you need multiple concurrent executions this also works for each thread separately.

Comment: Yeah, it would be much more convenient to use time.sleep(5). However, the transmission time would be 5+alpha(processing time, which differs for each data type). And other side(receiver) wouldn't receive data at constant intervals. That's why i was trying to use threading.Event.